# Micromax A88 screen flashes white after booting in recovery mode

Tags: rooting, recovery-mode

I tried rooting my Android phone (Micromax A88) using Kingo Root for Windows. After rooting, I got root permissions, but recovery mode got corrupted.

After booting in recovery, screen just flashes white and device turns off. I have tried ROM manager and also Mobileuncle MTK Tools using Recovery Image but no luck.

How should I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Flash the Stock ROM using SP Flash Tool. If you go to Service Center, they'll charge unnecessary !

You need to download SP Flash Tool, Drivers for MMX A88 and the Stock ROM of the same.

Install Drivers in your PC and extract the Stock ROM, which will be incompressed file format.

Follow the detailed procedure [here](http://www.skyneel.com/2013/06/new-update-of-micromax-a88-canvas-music-stock-rom-v3.html)